Are mobile game companies responsible for NSFW ads in children's games?
Generally speaking, mobile games (especially those targeted towards children) operate on a free-to-play basis, with revenue coming from frequent advertising slots. Unfortunately, advertising providers often fail to do their due diligence moderating ads, so children are often exposed to malvertising and NSFW ads.
In such cases, is the company which developed the game liable for the inappropriate advertisements their games display? What ads to actually show is determined by the third-party advertising provider, but the companies which develop the games still give them permission to display said ads (and receive money for it.)

Ads are not just "determined by the third-party advertising provider", you configure parameters for the kinds of ads. I'm virtually certain that age-appropriateness is one of those parameters.

@Barmar However, in  the case of X/Twitter, I'm sure various companies were not expecting the ads that were served up next to their content.

@Barmar Such configuration options are far from perfect; for example, I often hear people complain about their kids being shown glorified hentai in the ads on kids' videos.

Of course. Our customers occasionally report ads that are against our preferences, and we report the problem to our ad provider. All we can do is make a best effort.
